# Yii2 updateAll() not triggering afterSave()

Tags: php, yii2

I have implemented some logic in afterSave method on every insert or update.

But afterSave is not executed where I have used updateAll().

So is there any alternative for the same ?

Comment: Save models in loop with standard `save()` method. The problem is it's slower and consumes more memory. Or if possible move the logic from `afterSave()` to separate method that you can simply call after `updateAll()`.

Comment: how to implement that "after updateAll" method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`afterSave()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave()-detail) is thought for a single record. [`updateAll()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-activerecord.html#updateAll()-detail) handles many records in a completly different way. So you cannot use `afterSave()` this way. Imagine: when you update thousands of records this way, the `afterSave()` methods would need to be executed for each record - you would probably need something like `afterSaveAll()` that gets called once and that does only a single (or some few) further update, right?

When you call `ActiveRecord::updateAll()` and you want that something happens afterwards (for all updated records) you have to do it explicitly after that call. Or you might could modify what you're doing with updateAll(). Otherwise you have to tell us in more detail what you try to achieve.

Or as Bizley has commented: if you you know that you are only updating a couple of records you could do it in a loop. So you would not use `updateAll()`, rather you update each record separatly, with a call of `save()` and the implicit call of `afterSave()` that you have already implemented. You could give it a try, it might be acceptable from an performance perspective.

Comment: you are right and I got the concept, so let me share more details, give me few minutes